# Cloudera VM Windows mouse only partially works

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am getting started with Cloudera Hadoop and downloaded the VMWare image from [here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera%27s+Hadoop+Demo+VM).  While the image itself works fine, my mouse does not.

I am running on a new MacBookAir, using VMWare for the Mac.  I created the image using the uncompressed image file, but was unsure which OS to select in VMWare.   I tried both Mac OS (which didn't even boot in the VM) and then Windows OS (which did boot).

The mouse behaves as follows in the VM.  Right click works fine, i.e. context-menu appears.  Left click does nothing.  I have tried to use the 'mouse' system setting to fix this, but that doesn't change anything.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working - a couple of things.  First I needed to re-create the VM using the correct OS (it is Linux - CentOS 5.8, and in my case 64-bit).

Next I needed to mount a CD drive (had to force shutdown and then re-start) via the Settings.  After that I had to install the VMWare Tools via the newly mounted CD (from the original source media).

After that I had to do a cold restart one more time, then voila - mouse is working ok.